# Making column value unique to one user only while others can have same value only once as well

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database

I have an option to allow each user to create their own profile categories. I want `user A` and `user B` to be allowed to have `cats` category, but I don't want user A to be able to have another category he already has so the name and slug has to be unique to his profile only so that all users can have `cats` category but same user can't have a duplicated `cats` category.

My categories table

```php
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->foreignId('user_id')
                ->constrained()
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Is it only allowed in validation? And if so, how to write the validation for this rule? That this column has to be a unique value only to this user but other users can have same value in their profiles.

Comment: I think you will need to define statement in `form request` to check if user already have the value in db or not. Yes it is not the best way, but I think it is only way possible

Comment: So it is allowed only in request validation? and do I have to create a custom validation rule for that or does Laravel has a helper that gets this done? I tried to search but I couldn't find any

Comment: I don't think there is ready method for this. But it is not that hard to do. Just access to table to find data with given `value` and user `id`. If it returns some data then your user already have the value, so you have to throw exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure there are no duplicated category names for a user, you need to make sure that the pair **user_id + name** is unique in **categories** table.

In order to do so, you need to define a **composite unique key** for those 2 columns:

```
$table->unique(["user_id", "name"]);
```

This way, the database won't allow any **user_id** to have multiple categories with the same **name**.

Comment: Should this replace $table->string('name'); and $table->string('user_id'); or it goes with them?

Comment: Those are field definitions. They need to stay. Once you defined the fields, you'll need to create the unique key on them.

Comment: So it goes like this
```
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->foreignId('user_id')
                ->constrained()
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->string('name');
            $table->unique(["user_id", "name"]);
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```
Am I correct?

Comment: Almost, you're missing the definition of user_id field. You need to define it first and only then you should define the foreign key that uses this column.

Comment: Fantastic! Will give it a shot now, thanks!